# Jenkins: Email checkstyle report

Tags: email, jenkins, checkstyle

I have configured Jenkins to generate Checkstyle report.
Now I want to get email of this report on regular basis say every week. 
How to configure Jenkinsto email this report

Comment: Did you had a chance to try this: https://github.com/jenkinsci/email-ext-plugin/blob/master/src/main/resources/hudson/plugins/emailext/templates/static-analysis.jelly